# How to disable php default error reporting on ubuntu 16

Tags: php

I want to turn off all the error reporting in php by default. I don't want to achieve this using php code in my website pages, I need some generic way overall.

My php version is 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: If you have access to php.ini you can add it there. Otherwise you can put it in .htaccess in root of your website.

Comment: Can you explain how? I have access to the whole server, please tell me both ways

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to fix the PHP code that is causing you problems

Comment: [PHP Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: Don't turn off error reporting if you do not have well-tested notification systems in place!

Comment: I have display_errors = Off in /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini and I am still getting errors

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right, but removing all the errors from php code is currently not feasible for me.

Comment: Check using `phpinfo()` that your Apache is using that `php.ini` file. Maybe its using some other `php.ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I am on the right file: /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini

Comment: What type of errors are you seeing? Are they Fatal Errors

Comment: When I see php.ini, its written: "display_errors  On - Off"
"display_startup_errors On - Off". The On is local value, and Off is Master Value, How can I switch Local value to Off?

Comment: I get Notice undefined index errors